# Colors missing after translating model to Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have an application that is translating models from Onshape to SVF format in Forge.  After the translation is complete the colors are missing in the Autodesk Viewer.
Here is an example I loaded into the online viewer:  https://autode.sk/2VKVqHB 
Does anyone know why the colors would not come across?
Are there any options in the translator that can affect colors?

Comment: Is the seed file a STEP file? which file format is it?

Comment: Yes, looks like it came from a STEP file.  I got the model from a public gallery for testing our Forge app, so I can send it to you if you want.

Comment: yes, please - to my firstname @autodesk.com